# How to position an icon alongside text?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm struggling to get a font-awesome icon alongside a heading and paragraph like in the picture below:

[image: Example of What I Want]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <div id="contenedor">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Nice Work</h2>
        <p>We possess within us two</p>
        <p>winds. So far I have written</p>
        <p>only of the conscious mind.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
  #contenedor {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .left h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .left p {
    line-height: 18px;
    color:#BDC3C7;
  }
  .right {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .right i {
    background: #1DCFD1;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color:#FFF;
  }
```

### **<kbd>[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sw5w4uv7/)</kbd>**